# Controller not getting executed using ocLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload, lazy-loading

I have added below config for controller

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
'debug': true, // For debugging 'true/false'
'events': true, // For Event 'true/false'
'modules': [{ // Set modules initially
name : 'usersCtrl', // State1 module
files: ['protected/controllers/usersCtrl.js']
}]
});
```

on route

```
$stateProvider.state('users', {
url: "/users",
views : {
"" : {
templateUrl:"protected/views/users.html"
}
},
resolve: {
loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
return $ocLazyLoad.load('usersCtrl'); // Resolve promise and load before view
}]
}
});
```

usersCtrl.js gets loaded i can see that in network but not executing. i kept console alert but nothing worker.

```
app.controller('usersCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $timeout, $http, $mdDialog,$stateParams,$mdToast,$sce,formatDate)

console.log("controller call");

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
console.log("ready");
});
});
```

None of the console getting call..even function not getting called.

Comment: Did you access the controller inside the html with ng-controller="userCtrl" ?

Comment: No , there was no need it was getting called with $stateProvider.state

Comment: Okey, didnt' know that, but if it will be loaded from the $stateProvide don't you need to define the controller name inside the views below the templateUrl?

Comment: That is syntax of lazy loading. loading controller file only when need not before that.

Comment: That is not what i meant. OzLazyLoad loads the file if it is needed but you never connect this loaded file to the template.

Comment: I see , so  html I added ng-controller="userCtrl". But it throws error function undefined. Any solution to this. ? Also tried to change it to angular.module('App).controller('usersCtrl', function ()
but still throws error

Comment: No like you said the $stateProvider will do it. But you need to say him the name inside the view object under "templateUrl". Just look it up on the official oclazyload doc. There is an example with the ui-router

Comment: I have already added that , you can check above sample code.